# Calculations differ slightly from LTSpice

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac, passive-networks

[image]

[image]

Can someone please help me find the step in my solution to this problem where I went wrong my answer differs from my ltspice simulation. Source frequency is 100Hz. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use a smaller timestep and why don't you explicitly state what the difference is that concerns you? Did you try running for a longer period of time to see if things settle down to a more accurate value?

Comment: Ahhh yes. Changing the timestep seems to work and the answers agree. I had no idea about that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Can someone please help me find the step in my solution to this
> problem where I went wrong my answer differs from my ltspice
> simulation*

Why don't you use a smaller timestep?

> *Ahhh yes. Changing the timestep seems to work and the answers agree. I
> had no idea about that. Thank you very much! – Swiss Gnome*